# How to concatenate JS files into bundle-main.js, bundle-top.js, bundle-player.js?

Tags: javascript, minify, parceljs

I have developed and maintain a multiplayer word game, since maybe 8-10 years:

[image: game screenshot]

The backend for the game is a Maven project producing a servlet, written in Java.

And the Javascript files are just printed by the Java code - here a VS Code screenshot:

[image: VS code screenshot]

I would like to modernize the frontend part of my application by concatenating and minifying the JavaScript files.

In my application there are 3 types of web pages:

- The main one, showing the Pixi.js + jQuery game
- The top page, showing a DataTables.net with all players
- Player profiles, showing the player statistics and a Leaflet.js map

I would like to use parcel to generate:

- bundle-main.js
- bundle-top.js
- bundle-player.js

I have tried to create the following package.json, but of course it does not work yet:

```
{
  "outputFormat": "global",
  "targets": {
    "bundle-main": {
      "source": [
        "./src/main/resources/js/Base.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Utils.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Settings.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Bookmarks.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Score.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Tile.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Fullscreen.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Board.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Exists.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Main.js"
      ],
      "distDir": "./src/main/resources/bundles/bundle-main"
    },
    "bundle-top": {
      "source": [
        "./src/main/resources/js/Top.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Utils.js"
      ],
      "distDir": "./src/main/resources/bundles/bundle-top"
    },
    "bundle-player": {
      "source": [
        "./src/main/resources/js/Base.js",
        "./src/main/resources/js/Utils.js"
      ],
      "distDir": "./src/main/resources/bundles/bundle-player"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "latest"
  }
}
```

And I would like to generate the 3 bundle files (for inclusion as a "classic" Javascript, while the Pixi.js, jQuery, DataTables.net, Leaflet.js are included via links to CDN).

Could someone please help me with my package.json file?

I have also asked my question at [Github discussions](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/9269).

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by tobifasc (thank you!) I have run the commands, but some of the produced files are empty and they are not concatenated together?

[image: zsh screenshot]

Comment: Try `npx parcel build --target bundle-top`

Comment: Thank you, now the commands run, but the files are not concatenated together to a single file, and some are empty? Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create three new files in `src/main/resources/js/`:

1. `bundle-main.js` which looks like this:

```js
import "./Base.js";
import "./Utils.js";
import "./Settings.js";
import "./Bookmarks.js";
import "./Score.js";
import "./Tile.js";
import "./Fullscreen.js";
import "./Board.js";
import "./Exists.js";
import "./Main.js";
```

2. `bundle-top.js` which looks like this:

```js
import "./Top.js";
import "./Utils.js";
```

3. and `bundle-player.js` which looks like this:

```js
import "./Base.js";
import "./Utils.js";
```

Then change your `package.json` to:

```
...
"targets": {
  "bundle-main": {
    "source": "./src/main/resources/js/bundle-main.js",
    "distDir": "./src/main/resources/bundles/"
  },
  "bundle-top": {
    "source": "./src/main/resources/js/bundle-top.js",
    "distDir": "./src/main/resources/bundles/"
  },
  "bundle-player": {
    "source": "./src/main/resources/js/bundle-player.js",
    "distDir": "./src/main/resources/bundles/"
  }
},
...
```

and run

```
$ npx parcel build --target bundle-top
$ npx parcel build --target bundle-main
$ npx parcel build --target bundle-player
```

Comment: Ah, they are like entry points?

Comment: Kind of. Parcel does all the "heavy lifitng", looks inside your imports and merges them together to your "bundle" files.

Comment: Thank you, but I hit some parcel bug there: `libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument`. I will try later again.

Comment: I have deleted the `src/main/resources/bundles/` dir and now parcel does not segfault anymore, but the produced .js files are mostly empty, only have few comments. Still thanks for your reply